# Setting image width inside iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I've looked and found only answers saying no. I dont believe this is not possible.

So I have several divs each with a class of `customad` as seen here:

```
 <div class="customad"></div>
```

**Inside each `div` is an `iframe` with an `img`.**

I need to set the `img` inside the `iframe` within each of the `customad divs`  with a `width of 857px`

Here's what I've tried:

```
.customad iframe img {
   width:857px;
}
```

Inside the main `jobs.css` file.

I also tried embedding the `jobsiframe.css` into the inframe itself doing this in javascript:

```
 var frames = window.frames;
 for(var i=0;i<frames.length;i++){
  var cssLink = document.createElement("link");
  cssLink.href = "/css/jobsiframe.css";  cssLink.rel = "stylesheet";
  cssLink.type = "text/css";
  frames[i].document.body.appendChild(cssLink);
 }
```

Not quite sure what to do.

Comment: The only thing that could make it possible: Are the iframes on the same domain as the parent site? (or do you have control over the children iframes' code?)

Comment: its on the ads server, not the production site server

Comment: Then, sorry, but unless the adserver offers an API for that purpose, you cannot, for obvious security reasons. The only way two frames on different domains can communicate is via [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage). But if the page on the other side is not set up to receive and treat those messages, it won't be possible...